# Is it possible to see which program created a table and/or last modified it?

Tags: sas, metadata

I am using SAS EG and am looking through some tables that I have saved within a library. I need to know where a certain table came from but I can't find any meta-info like that, e.g. which SAS program created it or last modified it. If someone knows a way then that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. 
No meta-info is stored about which "program" created or modified a table. Even the concept of a "program" is one that is relevant to you but not much to SAS. Your SAS server is sent code which it executes and it cares very little about the name of the SAS program or EG project said code comes from.

Assuming your SAS environment stores workspace server logs, your best hope would be to go through these looking for references to a certain table in the submitted code. With the included timestamps, user ids and printed code, you should find all the info you are looking for, but it would be a laborious process.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no direct way to see what specific program modified a dataset.  SAS keeps track of instructions sent to the processor; it's only relatively recently that you could even have more than one program open in the window at one time.

You can however tell *when* the dataset was created and last modified, which may give you the information you need (particularly if you log when you run programs).

If you want, you could also use the dataset label in your programs to add the program name to the dataset - but you'd have to do that proactively.

```
data want(label='myprogram.sas');
  set sashelp.class;
run;
```

Depending on how you run (Batch, DM SAS, EG, Studio, SAS CONNECT, etc.) there may be a macro variable containing the program name that you can add in all of your programs so to make it automatic.

For example, as you specify EG, there are a set of global macro variables that could be useful:

```
GLOBAL _CLIENTMACHINE '[machinename]'
GLOBAL _CLIENTPROCESSFLOWNAME 'Process Flow'
GLOBAL _CLIENTPROJECTNAME ''
GLOBAL _CLIENTPROJECTPATH ''
GLOBAL _CLIENTPROJECTPATHHOST ''
```

But again this is only helpful going forward, it's not something that's written to the dataset already, so wouldn't help you determine what happened in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers so far that no, I know of no record of the creating program in the metadata or anything like that. And if there was, I don't know how much I'd rely on it, given how often I and my colleagues use %include to source from external files - would the sourcing or sourced program be the one that gets listed?

Anyhow, I have been in a situation before that seems similar to yours, and one thing that actually worked in tracking down the program that created a mystery dataset was using filename pipe to search all programs on our network drive with a .sas extension for any of the common statements that could be used to create that table (e.g. "data libname.datasetname;").

Credit where credit is due: most of the following code was adapted from a white paper by Brian Varney. I wish I remembered more of the specifics.

```
filename pipedir pipe ' dir "<ENTER THE TARGET DIRECTORY TO SEARCH HERE>" /S' lrecl=5000;

data indata;
infile pipedir truncover;
input line $char1000.;
length directory $1000;
retain directory;
if line =' ' or
index(upcase(line),'<DIR>') or
left(upcase(line))=:'VOLUME' then
delete;
if left(upcase(line))=:'DIRECTORY OF' then
directory=left(substr(line,index(upcase(line),'DIRECTORY OF')+12));
if left(upcase(line))=:'DIRECTORY OF' then
delete;
if input(substr(line,1,10),?? mmddyy10.) = . then
substr(line,1,10)='12/31/2999';
date=input(substr(line,1,10),?? mmddyy10.);
format date mmddyy10.;
run;
proc sort data=indata;
by directory descending date;
run;

data Directory_Summary(drop=i line);
set indata;
by directory;
length filename $75;
retain number_of_files_in_directory directory_size;
if first.directory then
do;
number_of_files_in_directory=input(scan(line,2,' '),32.);
directory_size=input(scan(line,4,' '),comma32.);
end;
file_size=input(scan(line,4,' '),comma32.);
filename=' ';
do i=5 to 100;
filename=trim(left(filename))||' '||scan(line,i,' ');
if scan(line,i,' ')=' ' then
leave;
end;
if index(upcase(line),'FILE(S)') then
delete;
if date ge '30DEC2999'd then
delete;
run;

proc sql noprint;
select distinct directory into :dir1 - :dir9999
from directory_summary
where scan(lowcase(filename),-1,'.')='sas';
quit;
%let numdirs=&sqlobs.;
%put &numdirs.;
proc datasets nolist lib=work;
delete allprgs;
quit;

%macro getsasprgs;
%do i=1 %to &numdirs.;
data prgs;
length line sasprogram f $300;
infile "&&dir&i.\*.sas" FILENAME=f;
input;
sasprogram =f ;
linenum+1;
if lag(sasprogram) ne sasprogram then linenum=1;
line=_infile_;
run;
proc append base=allprgs data=prgs;
run;
%end;
%mend getsasprgs;
%getsasprgs;

proc sql;
select *
from allprgs
where lowcase(line) ? "<ENTER THE LINE OF CODE YOU WANT TO FIND HERE>";
quit;
```

Good luck.